# Creating many subpages, symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How should I create many subpages, which have the same structure of content?

Should I do for each subpage one controller and one twig template or maybe I can do one controller and one template for all pages? For example every subpage will have their gallery, QA forum.

Comment: i would say make 1 template file, and make the controller get the correct page based on the request and then fill the template vars. you can use a pages table in your database or something like that

Comment: can i create routes by geting slugs from database? Similarly with controller

Comment: if you just make send the unique page-id in the request also you can let the controller handle the rest, no need for more routes

Answer (score 0):

If your subpages are dynamic or they have certain unique properties for identification, You should do it with single `controller` and single `template`.

Even for a dynamic layout, you can opt for dynamic templates called from a single `Controller`.

Only if you need static parameter change in `url` structure or frequent change in your source of `resource`, go for a different controller.

**EDIT**

Below is a small code reference for what I am talking about.

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class LuckyController extends Controller{

    /**
     * @Route("/subpage/{slug}")
     */
    public function numberAction($slug)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $subPage = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:SubPage")->findBy(array('slug' => $slug));
        if (!$subPage) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Entity not found!');
        }

        return $this->render('default/sub_page.html.twig', array(
            'subpage' => $subPage
        ));
    }
}
```

I assume the sub-pages are stored in database and you  have `ORM` that handles the database operation via `EntityManager`

The output is through `twig` template.

Hope this helps.

Comment: First should i do a database table with all subpages and then for all of them routes, and controller which will have to compare request with this database?

Comment: You should have a `slug` property in your subpage, which should be unique and that should be part of the dynamic route parameter.

Comment: even if i want 100 subpages?

Comment: you can create as many as. I suggested to create slug in order to make each subpage url personalised, presentable and SEO friendly. If your subpages are not exposed to public, you can use the auto increment id.

Comment: class LuckyController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number/{max}")
     */
    public function numberAction($max)
    {
        $number = mt_rand(0, $max);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}

Comment: Yes thank you, seo 'll be importnant. Sorry, bad code formatting, so for each subpage i should do a function with unique paramater? If I will have one template i should send specific parameters to display good view.

Comment: No, You should have a single controller method and a single template. please check the code ref in my edited post. Hope that helps.